# Python plotly express scatter_3d: how to set aspect ratio to 1

Tags: python, plot, graph, plotly

The following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express    as plt 
n=10**4; x=10*np.random.rand(n,2); 
x=np.array([5*x[:,0]*np.cos(x[:,1]),2*x[:,0]*np.sin(x[:,1]),0.5*np.random.rand(n)]).T; 
x=x[((x[:,0]-20)**2+x[:,1]**2-5**2)*((x[:,0]+20)**2+x[:,1]**2-10**2)>0]
x=pd.DataFrame(x,columns=['x','y','z']); 
fig=plt.scatter_3d(data_frame=x,x='x',y='y',z='z'); fig.show()
```

produces
[image]
instead of something like this but in 3D (very thin punctured ellipse):
[image]
How can I force the axes in the plot to have equal aspect ration (equal scale, though not necessarily starting at 0, i.e. possibly translated)?